# Android Error: Too Many Attribute Refrerences

Tags: android, attributes, widget

What does this error mean:

```
    W/ResourceType﹕ Too many attribute references, stopped at: #######
```

I get it when instantiating widgets programmatically using a context and a style reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error occurs when you use the following syntax:

```
    TextView tvMyTextView = new TextView(new ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.styleMyTextView));
```

To avoid it, rather than instantiating the control with the above context, instantiate it with a valid application context:

```
    TextView tvMyTextView = new TextView(context);
```

and then set the style attributes (like font size, colors, etc...) programmatically using the widget setters.

Comment: This answer does not provide the explanation asked in the question. However, it provides a good solution.

Comment: Unfortunately, when working through this problem, there WAS no explanation for the error.  This might be different today, but the error message and all online support could not explain it - I simply figured out a way to fix it.  (I suspect it was an error in documentation or implementation that was not documented.)